# Android get date from datepicker

Tags: android, datepicker

I have checked multiple threads but none of them seem to answer my question. From the Android Dev site I created a date picker fragment:

```
public class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment implements
DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener{

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

    }
}
```

in my activity I just call:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v){
    DialogFragment dateFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    dateFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

How do I pass the date that the user picks from the picker back to the activity? Essentially I just want to set a text field to that date:

```
mTextField.set(*The date*);
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to put your `DatePickerFragment` as a **inner class** in your `activity`, and when the user is done filling the date you can then use the `onDateSet` to set the text of your `mTextField`.

```
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
   mTextField.set(*The date*); //make sure that DatePickerFragment is an inner class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
pickDate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pick_date_new);
    pickDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            DialogFragment datePickerFragment = new DialogFragment() {
                DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener listener = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker datePicker, int i, int i1, int i2) {
                        dateLabel.setText(i2 + "/" + (i1 + 1) + "/" + i);
                    }
                };

                @Override
                public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), listener, 1970, 0, 1);
                }

            };
            datePickerFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
        }
    });
```